# List Linux kernel markers in alphabetical order

Tags: command-line, kernel

How can I get an alphabetical list of [kernel markers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_marker) from command-line?

Comment: Entirely too vague to be meaningful.

Comment: What do you mean by "kernel markers"? If you could clarify that, you may get better answer. In general, command `sort` can be used to sort strings alphabetically.

Comment: Should be moved to `Unix and Linux`. I think there are people on that stackexchange who can answer this question

Answer (score 7):

Kernel markers were [removed](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=commitdiff;h=fc5377668c3d808e1d53c4aee152c836f55c3490) entirely from the Linux kernel in version 2.6.32.

As of December 2009, there aren't any.

Answer (score 4):

As Stefano says, Kernel markers were removed. If you want something similar, see Tracepoints. There are some details about it here: http://netsplit.com/2011/03/07/tracing-on-linux/